# Checking if every user in the guild has certain emojis in their nickname

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a Christmas bot for my server. A private bot and I wonder how I can make it so that the bot checks every hour if a user has certain emojis in their guild username. If they do, they will get the Christmas role and if they don't have certain emojis, they won't get the role of course.

But it also needs to remove immediately if someone removes the emojis from their nickname. How can I do that?

This is what I have this far:

```js
let roleKerst = fs.readFileSync('./database/role.txt').toString();

client.once('ready', () => {
    const userArray = client.guilds.cache.get(guild).members.fetch()
    function nieuweFunctie(){
      if (roleKerst == 'aan') {
        //const user2 = userArray?.nickname

        // userArray.forEach(user34 => {
        // const user2 = user34.nickname
        // console.log('nickname', user2)
        // })

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(userArray, userKip => {
          console.log(userKip)
        });
        let nicknameEmoji = userKip.nickname
        //const user2 = userArray.nickname
        //console.log('nickname', user2)

        if (nicknameEmoji.includes('') || nicknameEmoji.includes('')) {
          //client.members.roles.add('1042423440264663160')
          console.log('They have the emoji in their name')
        } else if (!nicknameEmoji.includes('') || !nicknameEmoji.includes('')) {
          //client.members.roles.remove('1042423440264663160')
          console.log('They do not have the emoji in their name')
        }
        //})
        console.log('timer is working')
      } else {
        console.log('timer is off')
      }
    }
    setInterval(nieuweFunctie, 10000)


});
```

Comment: Avoid heavy operations on loop, use `onNicknameChanged` event or whatever it is after initializing

Comment: How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is definitely not something you want to use for this.

You should use the [`guildMemberUpdate` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) for this. Don't forget that you'll need the `Guilds`, `GuildMembers` and `GuildPresences` intents for this to fire.

The callback function will take two parameters; the `oldMember` is the first one and the `newMember` is the second one. You can use these two objects to check what changes the member made.

For example, you can check if the `oldMember`'s nickname included any of the emojis. If it included and `newMember`'s nickname doesn't have any of them, you know that they removed it from their nickname.

To check if they added an emoji, you'll check if the `oldMember` doesn't have any and if the `newMember` has at least one of them. You can use the [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method for this.

See the example below. It does exactly what you wanted.

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
  ],
});

client.on('guildMemberUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // if member hasn't changed their nickname, just exit early
  if (oldMember.nickname === newMember.nickname) return;

  const christmasEmojis = ['', ''];
  const CHRISTMAS_ROLE_ID = 'YOUR ROLE ID HERE';
  const userTag = newMember.user.tag;
  const hasChristmasRole = newMember.roles.cache.has(CHRISTMAS_ROLE_ID);
  const isEmojiAdded =
    !christmasEmojis.some((emoji) => oldMember.nickname?.includes(emoji)) &&
    christmasEmojis.some((emoji) => newMember.nickname?.includes(emoji));
  const isEmojiRemoved =
    christmasEmojis.some((emoji) => oldMember.nickname?.includes(emoji)) &&
    !christmasEmojis.some((emoji) => newMember.nickname?.includes(emoji));

  console.log(`ℹ ${userTag} has changed their nickname from ${oldMember.nickname} to ${newMember.nickname}`);

  if (isEmojiAdded) {
    console.log(`ℹ ${userTag} has added a Christmas emoji to their nickname`);

    if (hasChristmasRole)
      return console.log(`ℹ ${userTag} already has the Christmas role`);

    try {
      await newMember.roles.add(CHRISTMAS_ROLE_ID);

      return console.log(`ℹ ${userTag} now has the Christmas role`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error adding role to member', error);
    }
  }

  if (isEmojiRemoved) {
    console.log(`ℹ ${userTag} has removed a Christmas emoji from their nickname.`);

    if (!hasChristmasRole)
      return console.log(`ℹ ${userTag} doesn't have the Christmas role`);

    try {
      await newMember.roles.remove(CHRISTMAS_ROLE_ID);

      return console.log(`ℹ ${userTag} now doesn't have the Christmas role`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error removing role from member', error);
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to check all this on the `ready` event, you'll need to fetch all members and iterate over the returned collection using [`Collection#each`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=each):

```js
const members = await client.guilds.cache.get(guild)?.members.fetch();

members.each(member => {
  if (christmasEmojis.some((emoji) => member.nickname?.includes(emoji)))
    // check if the member has the role and/or add it
  if (!christmasEmojis.some((emoji) => member.nickname?.includes(emoji)))
    // check if the member has the role and/or remove it
});
```